# add button inside a text view

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a text view in which i want a button for camera. In my application i want that user type some text then he/she want to attach a photo or video. I have done that but the camera button i want inside the text view. when i try to add a button as subview that button scrolled  with the text but i want button fixed and another problem is that the text comes in button area not visible so i want that the cursor will not go in that area  which is covered by button.

```
UIButton *myButton  =   [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame      =   CGRectMake(0, 0, 50.0, 30.0);

[editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
[txtView addSubview:myButton];
```

Answer (score 5):

[image] - [image]

- Try this .It will definitely work  for you and will solve your issue
- Write below code in ViewDidLoad Method.

  .

> ```
> -(void)textResizeForButton{
>
>     CGRect buttonFrame = self.button.frame;
>     UIBezierPath *exclusivePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:buttonFrame];
>     self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[exclusivePath];
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Add it on `self.view` not on `UITextField` so it won't be scrolled anywhere. Just get the `CGrect` right.

For offsetting the text on the right to fit `UIButton` try this:

```
    UIView *rightMarginView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, leftMargin, txtField.frame.size.height)];
    rightMarginView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [txtField setRightView:rightMarginView];
    txtField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: @user1672134 clear you self first what are you actuly want. first you wish to appear button on fixed area and youdont want to cut of text. un realted logic

Comment: The button should view in area of text view and the line in which area the button falls should not have text. the button and the text view should look like one component

Comment: rightViewMode and setRightView are the properties of UITextFiled not UITextView