# How to add UIButton inside UITextView in ios?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextview

I'm getting stuck how to put UIButton inside UITextView on bototm right side, there is one more requirement when user type in textview the text doesn't overlap on button. Below images is my requirement. How can I achieve this?Thanks

Comment: Why would you put a button inside a text view? Why not add the button below the text view?

Comment: @rmaddy because my requirement is textview contain camera button on right hand side so user write sometext and if they want to attached an image they click on button and attached an image...

Comment: Why not add the button to the right of the text view?

Comment: Take a look at the messages app as well as some others like WhatsApp. None of them put the camera button directly into the text field but in a bar that contains the text field and the buttons. I'd go that way. That also solves the issue for overlapping text.

Comment: Go through this link.it may help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107948/add-button-inside-a-text-view

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think you need to put the textView then place a View on top of the textView and then add the button inside the View.

Comment: can you give code example how can I implement it, I'm new in ios development hope u don't mide.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `UIButton` inside `UITextview` programmatically.

```
textview.addsubview(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is put the UIButton/UIView below the UITextView in the storyboard. Since elements placed in storyboard are w.r.t Z axis.  Something like this 
[image]

Then give bottom and trailing constraint only so that the position of the UIView remains the same even if the UITextView is growing in height dynamically